# Can i use @Component with @Entity?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

In my spring boot project(e-library) auto-cofiguration is not working properly.My ElibApplication.java is inside com.pk package which is annotated with @SpringBootApplication.My Entity class is inside com.pk.bean which is annotated with @Entity(from javax.persistence.Entity).As per the spring boot docs it should scan all the sub-package of com.pk.

When i use @component with @Entity its working.
Also when i use @ComponentScan({"com.pk.bean"}) in ElibApplication.java its working for me.

Comment: Sub package scan should work by default! If "@Component" is working but not the "@Entity", it may be an issue with your Database connection.Please check if your DB connection is eshtablished properly on startup.Look for any error. Or simply make a TestJDBC class with main and check if db is accessible by app!!

Comment: @Rahul this is not Database connection issue as table is getting created while runing the application

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `@Component` for this. Normally, it should pick up entities within subpackages, but you can use `@EntityScan` to  make sure it picks up your entities. Perhaps you have a conflicting `@EntityScan` somewhere that causes this issue in the  first place.

Comment: @EntityScan({"com.pk.bean"}) this is also not working